# Are there any useful libraries for .NET Console applications?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I'm wondering if there are any useful (free) libraries out there to
help the development of Console applications.

Just a simple example:

What about a library that encapsulates all the behaviour to 
select files in a console application (aka the OpenFileDialog for Console applications).

There's MonoCurses of course, but I'm wondering if there are others?

Thnx.
**UPDATE:**
I know you can simply use the OpenFileDialog of course. But I'm talking about pure console applications. No Windows Forms or WPF elements. Pure console only. (For example to run on a Linux system without a graphical user interface).

Comment: (deleted my answer since it wasn't helping...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one Good code I have used for Parsing the Command Line Arguments while using the Console Application [Command Line Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/command_line.aspx)

Comment: I cannot open the link but that might be a chinese firewall problem :p Thnx !

Comment: Personally I prefer Mono.Options for that purpose. http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Oct-14.html